# Kendo Tree View source binding

Tags: json, mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui, treeview

I need to bind the below Json to MVVM

```
model ={
        "dynamicFields":[
           {
               "name":"A1",
               "type":"LookUp",
               "required":true,
               "list":[
                  {
                      "Id":"f3373d59-27f2-4f4a-b9e4-9fd3ad468d6f",
                      "Name":"FruitItem1",
                      "expanded":false,
                      "items":[

                      ],
                      "IsActive":true
                  },
                  {
                      "Id":"feb67602-5f45-4fcd-857a-a26570144dff",
                      "Name":"FruitItem2",
                      "expanded":true,
                      "items":[
                         {
                             "Id":"16cf25ba-3c8b-4fa2-ad33-aaac242a0fa4",
                             "Name":"FruitItem3",
                             "expanded":false,
                             "items":[ ],
                             "IsActive":true
                         }
                      ],
                      "IsActive":true
                  }
               ],
               "IsMultiSelect":true,
               "IsMultiLevel":true
           }
        ],
        "ResourceId":"6fa1c8ce-98f7-40e6-bdac-f2770b9f4ef4",
        "ProjectId":null
    }
```

so I m converting this Json as follows

```
model.dynamicFields.forEach(function (item) {
        item.list = kendo.observableHierarchy(item.list);
    });

var viewModel = kendo.observable(model);
```

Now I m binding to template

```
kendo.bind($("#customfield"), viewModel);
```

Template as follows

[image]

```
<script id="fieldsTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div data-role="treeview"
             data-text-field="Name"
             data-bind="source: list"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now the treeview colapse and out of memory

if i remove the expanded property from model, the treeview comes but no expanding to sub items.

How can i fix this issue?

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/mvvm

(The above link is not useful for me because here source is directly in model property not as list )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Telerik

After further investigation, we reached to a conclusion that the desired scenario is not supported.
To explain what happens in this case, I need to shed more light how the MVVM source binding works. Basically, it listens to any changes that happen in it (in this case in the "dynamicFields"). If it detects changes, then it will re-generate the rendered content, which will lead to re-creation of the TreeView.

The change in the "dynamicFields" comes from the built-in TreeView behavior to update the "expanded" fields of its source. This action will trigger change, which will bubble to the "dynamicFields" and the result is "infinitive loop".

The only workaround in this case is to not use source binding for the TreeView. Check the updated demo that works:
http://dojo.telerik.com/IWAmo